# How often do desktop users switch tabs when browsing

Tags: user-behavior, tabs, browser

in order to optimize our user experience i've been trying find any insights on user behaviour for the 2 following

- average tabs open when browsing
- how often on average do users switch between tabs

for the 1st question i've been able to get some insights from the following studies.

https://dubroy.com/blog/how-many-tabs-do-people-use-now-with-real-data/
http://www.slate.com/articles/life/the_hive/2010/12/open_this_story_in_a_new_tab.html

but i haven't been able to find or come up with any logic that would help with the 2nd one. any ideas how this can be achieved?

Comment: The linked study is interesting, but am I the only one who thinks the maximum observed number of 25 open tabs at a time is *extremely low*? (current number of open tabs in my browser: 147, and I don't see that as unusual on my machines)

Comment: this study is focused on normal user. power users in the tech industry definitely have more tabs open on average but this is aimed at the normal user

Answer (score 1):

Hope this article [My CHI2010 Talk: A Study of Tabbed Browsing](https://dubroy.com/blog/my-chi2010-talk-a-study-of-tabbed-browsing/) might help

Comment: I like when answers are backed by research, however it would be nice to have it summed it up. Thank you anyway!